Density of a Random Variable in $\Bbb R^n $ using the fact that the topology is generated by hypercubes. topology
An answer to this question could be a large part of an answer of that one : vector of random variable with density
Here is the statement I want to prove :

Let $X\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random variable. Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying
$$ P(X\in I_1\times \ldots\times I_n)=\int_{I_1\times\ldots\times I_n}f(x_1,\ldots x_n)dx_1\ldots dx_n \hspace{1cm} (*) $$
for every interval $I_i\subset \mathbb{R}$ (note : infinite intervals like $I=(-\infty,a]$ are allowed).
Then $f$ is a density of $X$, that is :
$$ P(X\in B)=\int_Bf(x)dx  \hspace{2cm} (**) $$
for every Borel set $B$.

I'm pretty sure this is true because the cubes form a basis of the topology and the Borel sets are generated by this topology. Since the integral is $\sigma$-additive, formula (*) should pass through the "generation" processes.
Anyway, I'm not even sure how to prove formula (**) in the case of an open set since I cannot write an open set as an union of finitely many disjoint cubes...
QUESTIONS : is the statement true ? How to prove it ?

EDIT : full proof here :
https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/lefrido.pdf (in French). Search for the label PROPooCXSWooByucuN

Have you ever heard about Monotone class theorem (MCT), or $\pi-\lambda$ Dynkin system? This is a typical application of one of these theorems. Putting in short, if a statement is true for a $\cap$-stable collection of sets, then it's true for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that collection (this is not so precise, but you can think it that way).
